# TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to implement BCH codes in Pyton 3.7.
I am getting an error in the map function .
initially the code written was

```
Dvec = map(int, bin(D)[2:] )[::-1]
```

I tried using list as

```
Dvec = list(map(int, bin(D)[2:] )[::-1])
```

Still the error persists as

```
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable.
```

How to use this function now?

Comment: What is `D` in the above code?

Comment: Put the slice after the close parenthesis.

Comment: Close, but `list(map(int, bin(D)[2:] )[::-1])` needs to be `list(map(int, bin(D))[2:][::-1])` or else `map(int, bin(D)[2:] ` is still trying to index a `map` object

Comment: `map` doesn't return a list; it returns an instance of `map` (which is now a class, not a function), and `map` does not define `__getitem__`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried using the parenthesis after bin(D), but the error persists.

Comment: @maulshreeverma are you sure it's *the same error*? Not a different error? You need to provide a [mcve]. If the code I posted is till throwing an error, show us and post the full stack trace, or else we can only guess at what is going on

Comment: After code change
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "fuzzy_HMAC_tmp_3.py", line 99, in DisplayDir
    displayed_file()
  File "fuzzy_HMAC_tmp_3.py", line 166, in displayed_file
    enc = encode( 9, s)
  File "fuzzy_HMAC_tmp_3.py", line 72, in encode
    rem = poly_div(numerized_vin, genpoly)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\UNT\COURSES\sem2\RA\gfield.py", line 120, in poly_div
    Dvec = list(map(int, bin(D))[2:] [::-1])
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Before code change:  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "fuzzy_HMAC_tmp_3.py", line 99, in DisplayDir
    displayed_file()
  File "fuzzy_HMAC_tmp_3.py", line 166, in displayed_file
    enc = encode( 9, s)
  File "fuzzy_HMAC_tmp_3.py", line 72, in encode
    rem = poly_div(numerized_vin, genpoly)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\UNT\COURSES\sem2\RA\gfield.py", line 120, in poly_div
    Dvec = list(map(int, bin(D)[2:] )[::-1])
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Comment: The above two are the runtime exceptions. There is no error in code compilation

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dvec = list(map(int, bin(D)[2:]))[::-1]
```